Base of plant turned brown. Still good? Needs rescue?
Here's what it looks like:

Zoomed in you can see I cut one of them to see what is inside, before noticing there is also a root going into the ground above the cut, and before as well but not sure if that matters now that I cut it:

Finally here it is more zoomed showing the yellow/brown texture inside (is that dead?):

The other ones have roots too. Can they survive like this? Or do I need to cut the stems at the green parts and repot?
UPDATE: I cutoff the dead parts as per Kevin Skip's answer, repotted, and so far they are still alive. Looks like they will make it:


The roots are dead. Overwatering or low light are likely possibilities.
Cut the stems off cleanly with a knife. Ensure that the stem only has firm healthy tissue.
Either propagate in water or repot in soil.  Provide high light and go easy on the water until new growth appears.
